# CDN for RTMP live streaming URL

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn, rtmp

I am new into RTMP and live streaming.  We have a live stream URL rtmp://someIPaddress/match, that is getting from a 3rd party source.

what I am doing is installing flussonic streamer in an ubuntu machine in aws and put the live stream url in flussonic.

flussonic will provide a url which is using in my android app through which the end users are watching.

Is it possible to achieve CDN in my scenario?  I prefer to use aws CDN but I am confused. I have only used CDN when the images are stored in aws S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFront supports RTMP(distribution type) but only VOD, it cannot serve Live stream. The other and better way would be convert your RTMP live stream to HLS/DASH stream using Medialive and push it to Mediapackage and use CDN(CloudFront) to serve HLS/DASH stream, however I think it will be more costly then your current solution.

Comment: Thanks you!! Understood